# Cannot borrow as mutable in a loop when calling a closure that borrows as immutable?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

Here is the code:

```
fn test(){
    let mut numbers = vec![2];
    let f = || {
        for _ in numbers.iter(){
        }
        false
    };

    while false {
        let res = f();
        if res {
            numbers.push(10);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
   |
15 |     let f = || {
   |             -- immutable borrow occurs here
16 |         for _ in numbers.iter(){
   |                  ------- first borrow occurs due to use of `numbers` in closure
...
22 |         let res = f();
   |                   - immutable borrow later used here
23 |         if res {
24 |             numbers.push(10);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

But if I change the `while` keyword to `if`, it can be compiled. How to fix this? I want to call the anonymous function in a loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can simplify your example even more by replacing the closure by a simple immutable reference

```rust
let mut numbers = vec![2];
let r = &numbers;

while false {
    println!("{:?}", r);
    numbers.push(10);
}
```

Here we get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `numbers` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:7:5
  |
3 | let r = &numbers;
  |         -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
6 |     println!("{:?}", r); // use reference
  |                      - immutable borrow later used here
7 |     numbers.push(10);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

And like in your example, replacing the `while` with `if` makes the error go away. Why?

You probably know about the important Rust rule: **Aliasing nand mutability**. It states that, at any given time, a value can either be borrowed immutably arbitrarily many times *or* mutably exactly once.

The statement `numbers.push(10)` borrows `numbers` mutably temporarily (just for the statement). But we also have `r` which is an immutable reference. In order for `numbers.push(10)` to work, the compiler has to make sure that no other borrow exists at that time. But there exists the reference `r`! This reference cannot exist at the same time as `numbers.push(10)` exists.

Let's see for the `if` case first:

```rust
let mut numbers = vec![2];
let r = &numbers;            // <------+      (creation of r)   
                             //        |
if false {                   //        |
    println!("{:?}", r);     // <------+      (last use of r)
    numbers.push(10);
}
```

While the lexical scope means the variable `r` is only dropped at the end of the function, due to non-lexical lifetimes, the compiler can see that the last use of `r` is in the `println` line. Then the compiler can mark `r` as "dead" after this line. And this in turn means, that there is no other borrow in the line `numbers.push(10)` and everything works out fine.

And for the loop case? Let's imagine the loop iterating three times:

```rust
let mut numbers = vec![2];
let r = &numbers;            // <------+      (creation of r)   
                             //        |
// First iteration           //        |
println!("{:?}", r);         //        |
numbers.push(10);            //        |  <== oh oh!
                             //        |
// Second iteration          //        |
println!("{:?}", r);         //        |
numbers.push(10);            //        |
                             //        |
// Third iteration           //        |
println!("{:?}", r);         // <------+     (last use of r)
numbers.push(10);
```

As can be seen here, the time in which `r` is active overlaps `numbers.push(10)` (except the last one). And as a result, the compiler will produce an error because this code violates the central Rust rule.

And the explanation is the same for your closure case: the closure borrows `numbers` immutably and `f();` uses that closure. In the loop case, the compiler is not able to shrink the "alive time" of the closure enough to make sure it doesn't overlap the mutable borrow for `push`.

---

How to fix?

Well, you could pass `numbers` into the closure each time:

```rust
let mut numbers = vec![2];
let f = |numbers: &[i32]| {
    for _ in numbers.iter(){
    }
    false
};

while false {
    let res = f(&numbers);
    if res {
        numbers.push(10);
    }
}
```

This works because now, `numbers` is borrowed immutably also just temporarily for the `f(&numbers);` statement.

You can also use a `RefCell` as the other answer suggested, but that should be a last resort.

Comment: Why capturing borrowed content from outside is not working same as with passed argument ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden That's a good question. So the normal implementation of closures is an anonymous struct that contains all captured variables in it (and if captured by reference, those are references). So we basically have a struct containing an immutable reference to `numbers`. I'm not sure if environment could be automatically passed to the closure each time it is called. Not sure if that would be sound in all situations. Might be worth a proper SO question.

Comment: Very nice answer! +1 from me

Comment: Thank you, So the reason is that closures capture the variables when it is created, not when it's called.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but one way to solve this, without changing your code too drastically, would be to use `std::cell::RefCell` (described [**in the std**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) and [**in the book**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html)):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn test(){
    let numbers = RefCell::new(vec![2]);
    let f = || {
        for _ in numbers.borrow().iter(){
        }
        false
    };

    while false {
        let res = f();
        if res {
            numbers.borrow_mut().push(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a little bit tweaked demo, which actually does something:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    test();
}

fn test() {
    let numbers = RefCell::new(vec![0]);
    let f = || {
        for n in numbers.borrow().iter() {
            println!("In closure: {}", n);
        }
        println!();
        true
    };

    let mut i = 1;
    while i <= 3 {
        let res = f();
        if res {
            numbers.borrow_mut().push(i);
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    println!("End of test(): {:?}", numbers.borrow());
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> In closure: 0
>
> In closure: 0
> In closure: 1
>
> In closure: 0
> In closure: 1
> In closure: 2
>
> End of test(): [0, 1, 2, 3]
> ```

[**Rust Playground demo**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adf28cc367ef5dfc7d9825aef9ad3a15)